# How to solve (Jenkins) msbuild-by-convention issue illegal characters in path?

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, msbuild, msbuild-task

For a C# project I am using a Jenkins buildserver. To build the C# project I am using msbuild-by-convention. Since 2 months ago an error occured during every build attempt.

```
    (SetAssemblyFileVersion target) -> 
  C:\WORKSPACE\Backend\Back-End\msbuild-by-convention\Scripts\targets.msbuild(207,3): error MSB4018: The "Attrib" task failed unexpectedly. [C:\WORKSPACE\Backend\Back-End\Build\Scripts\main.msbuild]
C:\WORKSPACE\Backend\Back-End\msbuild-by-convention\Scripts\targets.msbuild(207,3): error MSB4018: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path. [C:\WORKSPACE\Backend\Back-End\Build\Scripts\main.msbuild]
```

The error occurs in this build-step/method:

```
<Target Name="SetAssemblyFileVersion">
    <!-- set correct file version -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <AssemblyInfoFiles Include="$(CSharpSourceDirectory)**\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Attrib ReadOnly="false" Files="@(AssemblyInfoFiles)" />
        <FileUpdate Files="@(AssemblyInfoFiles)" Regex="\[\s*assembly\s*:\s*AssemblyVersion\s*\(\s*&quot;[\d\.\*]+&quot;\s*\)\s*\]" ReplacementText="[assembly: AssemblyVersion(&quot;$(BuildVersion)&quot;)]" Condition=" @(AssemblyInfoFiles) != '' " />
            <FileUpdate Files="@(AssemblyInfoFiles)" Regex="\[\s*assembly\s*:\s*AssemblyFileVersion\s*\(\s*&quot;[\d\.\*]+&quot;\s*\)\s*\]" ReplacementText="[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(&quot;$(BuildVersion)&quot;)]" Condition=" @(AssemblyInfoFiles) != '' " />
</Target>
```

I did not change my build-script and before it was working. Does anyone have any idea how to solve or debug this issue?

Thanks a lot,
Jordy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are high chances that its permission issue. For time being try giving full access to your @(AssemblyInfoFiles) files to everyone( If it works then you can change the security permission on that file as you want.)

Comment: Is there a way I could verify? Which user needs what rights (read, write, full etc.)?

Comment: your jenkins services must be running under a service account? I think if you give access to that service account then it would solve your problem.

Comment: I gave access to the service account of Jenking, but this did not solve the issue. Are there any other things I could verify?

Comment: try using verbosity switch when calling your script which would give your detailed logs. It might slow down your build but you will get detailed log.

example:
msbuild MyProject.proj /t:All /v:diag

/v is for verbosity

Comment: I checked the permissions of the Jenkins user and it was configured correctly already. I cleaned the build-directory and started a new build. This solves the issue.